# Image border error in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In my site, The logo appears fine in firefox and chrome but in I.E, blue border appears.[image]

```
<img src="images/logo.png" style = "position:relative; top:40px;">
```

Comment: can you please add your code here

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "border-style:none;" to the image

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in you css

```
img{
border-style:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `style` attribute, add:

```
border: none;
```

IE adds blue borders to image within links. It's a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks. I already got the answer from jai. But thanks for the info about images with links. :)

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS, add:

```
img {border: 0;}
a img, a:active img, a:focus img {outline: 0;}
```